# What does CGLib's intercept actually return?

Tags: java, proxy, tostring, cglib

I'm trying to create my own lazy load implementation using CGLib, but i've faced some strange behavior that I cannot explain.

Here is what i'm doing.
Proxy instance is being created like follows:

```
public static <T> T newInstance(Long sourceId, SourceMapper<T> sourceMapper) {

    Class<?> proxyTargetType = sourceMapper.getType();
    //mapper will use provided sourceId in order to load real object from the DB
    Function<Long, T> mapper = sourceMapper.getMapper();

    return (T) Enhancer.create(proxyTargetType,
                               new DynamicProxy<>(sourceId, mapper));
}
```

Here is the usage of the code above:

```
Order order = new Order();
     try {
          //heavy object is being proxied
          long customerTariffId = rs.getLong("customer_tariff_id");
          order.setCustomerTariff(DynamicProxy
                          .newInstance(customerTariffId, CUSTOMER_TARIFF_MAPPER)); 
        }
```

Heavy object should be loaded only if any of its methods gets invoked:

```
public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args,
                        MethodProxy methodProxy) throws Throwable {
    T source = this.getSource(); // loads real object using sourceId and mapper
    if(source == null) return null;
    return method.invoke(source, args);
}
```

It works perfectly if `this.getSource()` loads some object.
But here what i'm getting if we assume, that `order.getCustomerTariff()` should return `null` (`this.getSource()` will return `null`)

```
LOG.debug("{}", order.getCustomerTariff());          //null    (1)
LOG.debug("{}", order.getCustomerTariff() != null);  //true    (2)
```

I assume, that for some reason `toString()` gets invoked at line (2), so i'm getting `String` `null` instead of literal `null`. That's why it is not equal to a literal `null` in the comparison clause.
How do you think, is there any way to return a regular `null` at line (2) and receive a correct value of `false` during that check?

**EDIT**
Class being proxied looks similar to this:

```
public class CustomerTariff extends DomainEntity {

    private Customer customer;
    //some other similar fields
    private Tariff tariff;

    public CustomerTariff() {
    }

    public CustomerTariff(Customer customer
                          Tariff tariff) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.tariff = tariff;
    }

    public CustomerTariff(Long id, Customer customer,
                          Tariff tariff) {
        super(id);
        this.customer = customer;
        this.tariff = tariff;
    } 
    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "CustomerTariff{" +
            "customer=" + customer +
            ", tariff=" + tariff +
            "} " + super.toString();
    }
}

public abstract class DomainEntity {

    private Long id;

    public DomainEntity() {}

    public DomainEntity(Long id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "DomainEntity{" +
               "id=" + id +
                '}';
       }
    }
```

Comment: What you do seems correct. Did you inspect the type of the returned value? Did you set a break point in your interceptor to check the correct value being returned?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter From the debugging session i understood, that `Enhancer.create(...)` generates the following value `obj = {CustomerTariff$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d66ba677} "null"` which is being set it `customerTariff` field. This value is being compared with `null` at line(2). I don't understand what that quoted null mean, but the thing is that `"null" != null` yields `true`

Comment: I assume that there is some constructor which defines a value that becomes part of the `toString` representation. I assume that you call the constructor but do not initialize some field that is being read. Could you provide the class being proxied?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter Yes, i can provide the class. I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are intercepting your `toString` method from your interceptor and you do not get the interception chain you expect. Specify a method filter that only hits the methods you want to intercept and you should get the expected result.